# NVIDIA persistence daemon continuously starting and stopping in syslog

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 17.10, performance, systemd

I am on Ubuntu 17.10 and have both an intel and Nvidia GTX 1060 card (the latter usually selected), with driver version **387.22**.

I have noticed the following entries in my `/var/log/syslog`:

- `Nov 22 18:46:36 [machine name omitted] systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...`
- [some unrelated entries]
- `Nov 22 18:46:36 [...] systemd[1]: Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.`
- [some unrelated entries]
- `Nov 22 18:46:36 [...] systemd[1]: Stopping NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...`
- `Nov 22 18:46:36 [...] nvidia-persistenced: PID file unlocked.`
- `Nov 22 18:46:36 [...] nvidia-persistenced: PID file closed.`
- `Nov 22 18:46:36 [...] nvidia-persistenced: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced`
- `Nov 22 18:46:36 [...] nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (1115)`
- `Nov 22 18:46:36 [...] gdm3: GdmDisplay: display lasted 1.202396 seconds`
- `Nov 22 18:46:36 [...] systemd[1]: Stopped NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.`

The weird part is that those entries (and a few related I might be omitting here) are occurring *continuously*, multiple times and sometimes within the same timestamp.

That sounds suspicious to me - why is the daemon continuously started and stopped this way and wouldn't that severely impact on performance?

I'm asking because I am still clueless as per why my machine performs so poorly (especially with regards to gaming) in 17.10, compared to 17.04 - see related [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967158/what-is-the-optimal-must-gather-for-laptop-self-shutdown-troubleshooting-likely).

Obviously the desktop and dependencies are prime suspects here, not so much the driver version (as I recall seeing the exact same with a previous version).

**Questions**

- Is the above reflecting a normal behavior, and if not, how to investigate/fix it?
- Could that relate to performance issues when running demanding applications, such as games?

**Edit**

Interestingly, if I log on with the old Unity desktop, these log entries do not seem to occur. 
Performance also seems a lot snappier from a pure desktop perspective (although it might be my imagination), but the gaming performance is quite the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this is an old problem, I've still encountered it myself on **Kubuntu 18.04** and **nvidia driver 390**. Namely, the nvidia-persistence daemon spams the screen during boot (sometimes, not always). Thus, my solution circumvents the standard nvidia daemon startup on system boot by using a **separate systemd service**.

Like stated before, it seems to be a misconfiguration of starting the nvidia-persistence daemon. More precisely, the udev rules seem to be the problem for me. Thus, I modified `/lib/udev/rules.d/71-nvidia.rules` and commented out the actions under power-off and power-on. Like mentioned in other answers, you may also comment out the lines for loading and unloading.

Now the daemon does not start on power-on. Consequently, we have to schedule the start of the daemon manually. We can achieve that by copying `/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service`, e.g.

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service /lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced-manual.service
```

Now modify `/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced-manual.service` to look something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
Wants=syslog.target
Requires=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -rf /var/run/nvidia-persistenced

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To enable the service, execute

```
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-persistenced-manual.service
```

and if the old service is still enabled, run

```
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-persistenced.service
```

This way, the daemon will start on system startup. Feel free to modify the line `ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced` to e.g. include `--verbose` or  `--user [...]`.

Keep in mind, that in my default way, the daemon is running with **root permissions**.  If you do not want this, make sure to run the daemon with the `--user` argument.

Altogether, this is not a perfect solution, but it was able to fix the bug on my system.

Comment: This solved the problem for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Awfully sorry for coming back this late - I overhauled the system back then and forgot all about this issue. I can't verify it works for me anymore but at least it did so for one user and the answer's well explained so I'm going to accept. Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

The entries are caused by an unnecessary configuration file from the Nvidia package:

- Run the command nvidia-smi from the shell, you must see somewhere on the left top "Persistence-M On".
- You can test if your Nvidia drivers work ok without "Persistence-M".
- Go to /lib/systemd/system/ . Here you will find a file called nvidia-persistenced.service. Rename or move.
- Go to /lib/udev/rules.d/
- Open as root the config file 71-nvidia.rules
- Comment out # the actions under power on and power off and loading and unloading.
- Restart and check.

Thanks to void75, forums.linuxmint.com