# Ubuntu 18.04 boot stuck at message “Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon” after installing nVidia 390.74

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

I seem to have a similar problem to this guy.

[Ubuntu 17.10 boot stuck at message "Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon" after installing nVidia 384.90](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973605/ubuntu-17-10-boot-stuck-at-message-started-nvidia-persistence-daemon-after-ins)

Is the only option to remove the nvidia drivers?
If so is the correct procedure to boot into recovery mode, select root and then delete the drivers in the terminal with the following commands?

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libcud*
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove cuda*
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nvidia*

Update!
I can't even apply the above fix because I also have the problem in the link below where my Ubuntu is stuck in a login loop when trying to enter my desktop. When I login, the screen gets black and soon after that the login screen comes back.

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Unfortunately the solutions in the link rely on your knowing your login but I don't (only the password).

In theory it seems that you can recover your login by going into recovery mode, but my keyboard and mouse won't work with recovery GUI!

It does seem to be catch 22!

Am I right in thinking at this stage the only option is to delete and reinstall ubuntu?

Thanks

Update 2:

The keyboard and mouse are usb and they work in the regular linux login screen (it's just that that login process has the looping bug).

Not only is the recovery mode GUI completely unresponsive after a few minutes it start's displaying a bunch of random commands all over the screen see image below)!

[image]

Comment: You should definitely be able to purge the drivers from the mode. What exactly is the problem with your keyboard and mouse - do they not respond at all? Are they ordinary usb keyboard and mouse? If possible try following this answer to enter the root shell and purge the drivers from there https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/783019

Comment: See edit to original question above the recovery mode GUI will not respond to keyboard/mouse commands and then after a few minutes I get the crazy output shown above.

Comment: Alright, that seems very weird. Judging by the errors there might be something else wrong here as well (the errors mention filesystem and disk issues). Only other think I can think is you can try booting to the recovery shell from a Live USB (or live CD), assuming that's not what we're seeing here.

Comment: Did you recover? Looking for some way of disabling all the new drivers

Answer (score 0):

If the problem only occurs due to the persistence daemon, you can disable the startup by modifying `/lib/udev/rules.d/71-nvidia.rules`, similar to [the first part of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138052/946140). 
If necessary, also execute

```
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-persistenced.service
```

If, in the end, you need the nvidia persistence daemon, you can try to apply the second part of the answer to see if it works for you.