# Nvidia Persistence Daemon/Login Loop 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login, brightness

I recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows after a Windows 10 Update broke my computer and the repair tools/fresh install repeatedly failed.

I installed 18.4.02 and things were going great until I tried to fix my brightness keys. I used this fix:
[Brightness problem Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

This caused a Nvidia Persistence Daemon issue to repeatedly stop and start.

I booted into Safe Mode and purged the Nvidia drivers, hoping that would fix things.

But now I'm stuck in a login loop and can't seem to get into my account. The username and pass are correct and I can use them to access the terminal. I re-installed the nvidia drivers, but this time as nvidia-390 (since I read that that's apparently a more stable version of the drivers, but then I get the Nvidia Persistence Daemon issue again.

My computer is an ASUS G75VW with the Nvidia GTX 660M graphics card. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm thinking since this I wouldn't be losing any files, it might be better to just re-install ubuntu. But I'd like to prevent a graphics card issue from messing me up again.

Comment: is there any news on this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope! I re-installed. I realized that the fix I used broke everything. Here's what I did: 1. Fresh install. 2. Auto update the Nvidia drivers. 3. create shortcuts for xbrightness. I don't think I had to install xbrightness, but once I set that up, that fixed all the issues I was having with my brightness keys (Which is why I messed with the Nvidia drivers in the first place). Now everything works great!

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is only with the persistence daemon, [this may fix it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138052/946140) (at least it did the job for me).

If you do **not** need nvidia persistence mode, you can also simply disable both cases in the udev rules that are mentioned in the answer and stop right there. This way, it will not start the persistence daemon, thus not cause any problems for you.

To determine whether you need the nvidia persistence daemon, you might want to read [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/index.html). (TL;DR: it increases the GPU performance)